# brew openshift-cli v4.3.8

Tags: macos, openshift, homebrew

I was wondering if there is a version of [brew] openshift-cli (stable or not) that supports OCP version 4.3? The current stable version is 4.1, and this works with 3.11 but we are in the process of upgrading to 4.3, and oc version 4.3.8 is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can do `brew install --HEAD openshift-cli` to have the latest release of the `openshift-cli`.

It looks like the openshift-cli changed the process a little bit, and that is why the formula missed a couple of releases. (based on my reading of the README).

Let me know if the `HEAD` build works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, I had to manually download the tarball and move the oc binary to my path (renamed to oc2)